# Remap Command/Apple key to work as the control key

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, lubuntu, keyboard-layout, apple

I have an iBook G4 running Lubuntu 12.04 LTS and I would like to re-map the <kbd>Command</kbd> (Apple) keys to work as control. I've looked at using xmodmap, but so far I have failed at it.

And, after trying the instructions here: askubuntu.com/questions/137172/how-to-remap-superleft-key-to-control-key neither the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key nor the <kbd>Command</kbd> key works as control. This most very perturbing.

This is what my `~/.Xmodmap` looks like:

```
keycode   8 =
keycode   9 = Escape NoSymbol Escape
keycode  10 = 1 exclam 1 exclam exclamdown U2044 exclamdown
keycode  11 = 2 at 2 at trademark EuroSign trademark
keycode  12 = 3 numbersign 3 numbersign sterling U2039 sterling
keycode  13 = 4 dollar 4 dollar cent U203A cent
keycode  14 = 5 percent 5 percent infinity UFB01 infinity
keycode  15 = 6 asciicircum 6 asciicircum section UFB02 section
keycode  16 = 7 ampersand 7 ampersand paragraph doubledagger paragraph
keycode  17 = 8 asterisk 8 asterisk enfilledcircbullet degree enfilledcircbullet
keycode  18 = 9 parenleft 9 parenleft ordfeminine periodcentered ordfeminine
keycode  19 = 0 parenright 0 parenright masculine singlelowquotemark masculine
keycode  20 = minus underscore minus underscore endash emdash endash
keycode  21 = equal plus equal plus notequal plusminus notequal
keycode  22 = BackSpace BackSpace BackSpace BackSpace
keycode  23 = Tab ISO_Left_Tab Tab ISO_Left_Tab
keycode  24 = q Q q Q oe OE oe
keycode  25 = w W w W U2211 doublelowquotemark U2211
keycode  26 = e E e E dead_acute acute dead_acute
keycode  27 = r R r R registered U2030 registered
keycode  28 = t T t T dagger dead_caron dagger
keycode  29 = y Y y Y yen onequarter yen
keycode  30 = u U u U dead_diaeresis diaeresis dead_diaeresis
keycode  31 = i I i I dead_circumflex U02C6 dead_circumflex
keycode  32 = o O o O oslash Oslash oslash
keycode  33 = p P p P Greek_pi U220F Greek_pi
keycode  34 = bracketleft braceleft bracketleft braceleft leftdoublequotemark rightdoublequotemark leftdoublequotemark
keycode  35 = bracketright braceright bracketright braceright leftsinglequotemark rightsinglequotemark leftsinglequotemark
keycode  36 = Return NoSymbol Return
keycode  37 = Control_L NoSymbol Control_L
keycode  38 = a A a A aring Aring aring
keycode  39 = s S s S ssharp dead_stroke ssharp
keycode  40 = d D d D partialderivative eth partialderivative
keycode  41 = f F f F function dead_hook function
keycode  42 = g G g G copyright dead_doubleacute copyright
keycode  43 = h H h H dead_abovedot dead_belowdot dead_abovedot
keycode  44 = j J j J U2206 onehalf U2206
keycode  45 = k K k K dead_abovering UF8FF dead_abovering
keycode  46 = l L l L notsign THORN notsign
keycode  47 = semicolon colon semicolon colon U2026 thorn U2026
keycode  48 = apostrophe quotedbl apostrophe quotedbl ae AE ae
keycode  49 = grave asciitilde grave asciitilde dead_grave dead_horn dead_grave
keycode  50 = Shift_L NoSymbol Shift_L
keycode  51 = backslash bar backslash bar guillemotleft guillemotright guillemotleft
keycode  52 = z Z z Z Greek_OMEGA dead_cedilla Greek_OMEGA
keycode  53 = x X x X approxeq dead_ogonek approxeq
keycode  54 = c C c C ccedilla Ccedilla ccedilla
keycode  55 = v V v V squareroot U25CA squareroot
keycode  56 = b B b B integral idotless integral
keycode  57 = n N n N dead_tilde U02DC dead_tilde
keycode  58 = m M m M mu threequarters mu
keycode  59 = comma less comma less lessthanequal dead_macron lessthanequal
keycode  60 = period greater period greater greaterthanequal dead_breve greaterthanequal
keycode  61 = slash question slash question division questiondown division
keycode  62 = Shift_R NoSymbol Shift_R
keycode  63 = KP_Multiply KP_Multiply KP_Multiply KP_Multiply KP_Multiply KP_Multiply XF86ClearGrab
keycode  64 = Alt_L Meta_L Alt_L Meta_L
keycode  65 = space NoSymbol space
keycode  66 = Caps_Lock NoSymbol Caps_Lock
keycode  67 = F1 F1 F1 F1 F1 F1 XF86Switch_VT_1
keycode  68 = F2 F2 F2 F2 F2 F2 XF86Switch_VT_2
keycode  69 = F3 F3 F3 F3 F3 F3 XF86Switch_VT_3
keycode  70 = F4 F4 F4 F4 F4 F4 XF86Switch_VT_4
keycode  71 = F5 F5 F5 F5 F5 F5 XF86Switch_VT_5
keycode  72 = F6 F6 F6 F6 F6 F6 XF86Switch_VT_6
keycode  73 = F7 F7 F7 F7 F7 F7 XF86Switch_VT_7
keycode  74 = F8 F8 F8 F8 F8 F8 XF86Switch_VT_8
keycode  75 = F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 XF86Switch_VT_9
keycode  76 = F10 F10 F10 F10 F10 F10 XF86Switch_VT_10
keycode  77 = Num_Lock NoSymbol Num_Lock
keycode  78 = Scroll_Lock NoSymbol Scroll_Lock
keycode  79 = KP_Home KP_7 KP_Home KP_7
keycode  80 = KP_Up KP_8 KP_Up KP_8
keycode  81 = KP_Prior KP_9 KP_Prior KP_9
keycode  82 = KP_Subtract KP_Subtract KP_Subtract KP_Subtract KP_Subtract KP_Subtract XF86Prev_VMode
keycode  83 = KP_Left KP_4 KP_Left KP_4
keycode  84 = KP_Begin KP_5 KP_Begin KP_5
keycode  85 = KP_Right KP_6 KP_Right KP_6
keycode  86 = KP_Add KP_Add KP_Add KP_Add KP_Add KP_Add XF86Next_VMode
keycode  87 = KP_End KP_1 KP_End KP_1
keycode  88 = KP_Down KP_2 KP_Down KP_2
keycode  89 = KP_Next KP_3 KP_Next KP_3
keycode  90 = KP_Insert KP_0 KP_Insert KP_0
keycode  91 = KP_Delete KP_Decimal KP_Delete KP_Decimal
keycode  92 = ISO_Level3_Shift NoSymbol ISO_Level3_Shift
keycode  93 =
keycode  94 = section plusminus section plusminus section plusminus section
keycode  95 = F11 F11 F11 F11 F11 F11 XF86Switch_VT_11
keycode  96 = F12 F12 F12 F12 F12 F12 XF86Switch_VT_12
keycode  97 =
keycode  98 = Katakana NoSymbol Katakana
keycode  99 = Hiragana NoSymbol Hiragana
keycode 100 = Henkan_Mode NoSymbol Henkan_Mode
keycode 101 = Hiragana_Katakana NoSymbol Hiragana_Katakana
keycode 102 = Muhenkan NoSymbol Muhenkan
keycode 103 =
keycode 104 = KP_Enter NoSymbol KP_Enter
keycode 105 = Control_R NoSymbol Control_R
keycode 106 = KP_Divide KP_Divide KP_Divide KP_Divide KP_Divide KP_Divide XF86Ungrab
keycode 107 = Print Sys_Req Print Sys_Req
keycode 108 = ISO_Level3_Shift NoSymbol ISO_Level3_Shift
keycode 109 = Linefeed NoSymbol Linefeed
keycode 110 = Home NoSymbol Home
keycode 111 = Up NoSymbol Up
keycode 112 = Prior NoSymbol Prior
keycode 113 = Left NoSymbol Left
keycode 114 = Right NoSymbol Right
keycode 115 = End NoSymbol End
keycode 116 = Down NoSymbol Down
keycode 117 = Next NoSymbol Next
keycode 118 = Insert NoSymbol Insert
keycode 119 = Delete NoSymbol Delete
keycode 120 =
keycode 121 = XF86AudioMute NoSymbol XF86AudioMute
keycode 122 = XF86AudioLowerVolume NoSymbol XF86AudioLowerVolume
keycode 123 = XF86AudioRaiseVolume NoSymbol XF86AudioRaiseVolume
keycode 124 = XF86PowerOff NoSymbol XF86PowerOff
keycode 125 = KP_Equal NoSymbol KP_Equal
keycode 126 = plusminus NoSymbol plusminus
keycode 127 = Pause Break Pause Break
keycode 128 = XF86LaunchA NoSymbol XF86LaunchA
keycode 129 = KP_Decimal KP_Decimal KP_Decimal KP_Decimal
keycode 130 = Hangul NoSymbol Hangul
keycode 131 = Hangul_Hanja NoSymbol Hangul_Hanja
keycode 132 =
keycode 133 = Control_L NoSymbol Control_L
keycode 134 = Super_R NoSymbol Super_R
keycode 135 = Menu NoSymbol Menu
keycode 136 = Cancel NoSymbol Cancel
keycode 137 = Redo NoSymbol Redo
keycode 138 = SunProps NoSymbol SunProps
keycode 139 = Undo NoSymbol Undo
keycode 140 = SunFront NoSymbol SunFront
keycode 141 = XF86Copy NoSymbol XF86Copy
keycode 142 = SunOpen NoSymbol SunOpen
keycode 143 = XF86Paste NoSymbol XF86Paste
keycode 144 = Find NoSymbol Find
keycode 145 = XF86Cut NoSymbol XF86Cut
keycode 146 = Help NoSymbol Help
keycode 147 = XF86MenuKB NoSymbol XF86MenuKB
keycode 148 = XF86Calculator NoSymbol XF86Calculator
keycode 149 =
keycode 150 = XF86Sleep NoSymbol XF86Sleep
keycode 151 = XF86WakeUp NoSymbol XF86WakeUp
keycode 152 = XF86Explorer NoSymbol XF86Explorer
keycode 153 = XF86Send NoSymbol XF86Send
keycode 154 =
keycode 155 = XF86Xfer NoSymbol XF86Xfer
keycode 156 = XF86Launch1 NoSymbol XF86Launch1
keycode 157 = XF86Launch2 NoSymbol XF86Launch2
keycode 158 = XF86WWW NoSymbol XF86WWW
keycode 159 = XF86DOS NoSymbol XF86DOS
keycode 160 = XF86ScreenSaver NoSymbol XF86ScreenSaver
keycode 161 =
keycode 162 = XF86RotateWindows NoSymbol XF86RotateWindows
keycode 163 = XF86Mail NoSymbol XF86Mail
keycode 164 = XF86Favorites NoSymbol XF86Favorites
keycode 165 = XF86MyComputer NoSymbol XF86MyComputer
keycode 166 = XF86Back NoSymbol XF86Back
keycode 167 = XF86Forward NoSymbol XF86Forward
keycode 168 =
keycode 169 = XF86Eject NoSymbol XF86Eject
keycode 170 = XF86Eject XF86Eject XF86Eject XF86Eject
keycode 171 = XF86AudioNext NoSymbol XF86AudioNext
keycode 172 = XF86AudioPlay XF86AudioPause XF86AudioPlay XF86AudioPause
keycode 173 = XF86AudioPrev NoSymbol XF86AudioPrev
keycode 174 = XF86AudioStop XF86Eject XF86AudioStop XF86Eject
keycode 175 = XF86AudioRecord NoSymbol XF86AudioRecord
keycode 176 = XF86AudioRewind NoSymbol XF86AudioRewind
keycode 177 = XF86Phone NoSymbol XF86Phone
keycode 178 =
keycode 179 = XF86Tools NoSymbol XF86Tools
keycode 180 = XF86HomePage NoSymbol XF86HomePage
keycode 181 = XF86Reload NoSymbol XF86Reload
keycode 182 = XF86Close NoSymbol XF86Close
keycode 183 =
keycode 184 =
keycode 185 = XF86ScrollUp NoSymbol XF86ScrollUp
keycode 186 = XF86ScrollDown NoSymbol XF86ScrollDown
keycode 187 = parenleft NoSymbol parenleft
keycode 188 = parenright NoSymbol parenright
keycode 189 = XF86New NoSymbol XF86New
keycode 190 = Redo NoSymbol Redo
keycode 191 = XF86Tools NoSymbol XF86Tools
keycode 192 = XF86Launch5 NoSymbol XF86Launch5
keycode 193 = XF86Launch6 NoSymbol XF86Launch6
keycode 194 = XF86Launch7 NoSymbol XF86Launch7
keycode 195 = XF86Launch8 NoSymbol XF86Launch8
keycode 196 = XF86Launch9 NoSymbol XF86Launch9
keycode 197 =
keycode 198 =
keycode 199 = XF86TouchpadToggle NoSymbol XF86TouchpadToggle
keycode 200 = XF86TouchpadOn NoSymbol XF86TouchpadOn
keycode 201 = XF86TouchpadOff NoSymbol XF86TouchpadOff
keycode 202 =
keycode 203 = Mode_switch NoSymbol Mode_switch
keycode 204 = NoSymbol Alt_L NoSymbol Alt_L
keycode 205 = NoSymbol Meta_L NoSymbol Meta_L
keycode 206 = NoSymbol Super_L NoSymbol Super_L
keycode 207 = NoSymbol Hyper_L NoSymbol Hyper_L
keycode 208 = XF86AudioPlay NoSymbol XF86AudioPlay
keycode 209 = XF86AudioPause NoSymbol XF86AudioPause
keycode 210 = XF86Launch3 NoSymbol XF86Launch3
keycode 211 = XF86Launch4 NoSymbol XF86Launch4
keycode 212 = XF86LaunchB NoSymbol XF86LaunchB
keycode 213 = XF86Suspend NoSymbol XF86Suspend
keycode 214 = XF86Close NoSymbol XF86Close
keycode 215 = XF86AudioPlay NoSymbol XF86AudioPlay
keycode 216 = XF86AudioForward NoSymbol XF86AudioForward
keycode 217 =
keycode 218 = Print NoSymbol Print
keycode 219 =
keycode 220 = XF86WebCam NoSymbol XF86WebCam
keycode 221 =
keycode 222 =
keycode 223 = XF86Mail NoSymbol XF86Mail
keycode 224 = XF86Messenger NoSymbol XF86Messenger
keycode 225 = XF86Search NoSymbol XF86Search
keycode 226 = XF86Go NoSymbol XF86Go
keycode 227 = XF86Finance NoSymbol XF86Finance
keycode 228 = XF86Game NoSymbol XF86Game
keycode 229 = XF86Shop NoSymbol XF86Shop
keycode 230 =
keycode 231 = Cancel NoSymbol Cancel
keycode 232 = XF86MonBrightnessDown NoSymbol XF86MonBrightnessDown
keycode 233 = XF86MonBrightnessUp NoSymbol XF86MonBrightnessUp
keycode 234 = XF86AudioMedia NoSymbol XF86AudioMedia
keycode 235 = XF86Display NoSymbol XF86Display
keycode 236 = XF86KbdLightOnOff NoSymbol XF86KbdLightOnOff
keycode 237 = XF86KbdBrightnessDown NoSymbol XF86KbdBrightnessDown
keycode 238 = XF86KbdBrightnessUp NoSymbol XF86KbdBrightnessUp
keycode 239 = XF86Send NoSymbol XF86Send
keycode 240 = XF86Reply NoSymbol XF86Reply
keycode 241 = XF86MailForward NoSymbol XF86MailForward
keycode 242 = XF86Save NoSymbol XF86Save
keycode 243 = XF86Documents NoSymbol XF86Documents
keycode 244 = XF86Battery NoSymbol XF86Battery
keycode 245 = XF86Bluetooth NoSymbol XF86Bluetooth
keycode 246 = XF86WLAN NoSymbol XF86WLAN
keycode 247 =
keycode 248 =
keycode 249 =
keycode 250 =
keycode 251 =
keycode 252 =
keycode 253 =
keycode 254 =
keycode 255 =
clear Control
clear mod4
remove Control = Control_L Control_R
remove mod4 = Super_L Super_R
add Control = Super_L
```

How can I change the Apple/Command key to work as Control? Should I use xkeymap or an app? And is it any different for Lubuntu than vanilla Ubuntu?

One other thing I've noticed is that I will randomly jump to a page or around a text editor, but this may just be system lag.

**EDIT** I was having a problem during my experimentation that was making it so both <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Command</kbd> worked like Command, not doing anything. This was really annoying, but I fixed it by removing the last 5 lines in ~/.Xmodmap.

Answer (score 0):

I remapped my command key to work exactly like the control key with these steps:

1. Use `xev` to find the keycode of the command key, mine was 133
2. Run the following:

   ```
   xmodmap -e "keycode 133 (replace with your keycode) = Control_L"
   xmodmap -e "remove mod4 = Control_L"
   xmodmap -e "add control = Control_L"
   ```